# Software RAID slows down while emptying buffer

Tags: filesystems, performance, raid, xfs

I am experimenting with `mdraid` in CentOS 7.6, trying to understand these results from `fio`.  I am doing a sequential write to a 4 stripe array, and the speed starts out good while it writes to the RAM buffer, then it slows down during fsync.
I'm using `end_fsync` to make sure the data gets written to disk.  During this test I am monitoring the 4 disks with `iostat` in another window.

In the beginning, `iostat` shows 165MBps on each disk, and `fio` shows write speed over 3000MBps.  So we are writing to RAM, and the kernel is simultaneously writing to disk.  Once fio finishes writing, it flushes the buffer to disk.  During this time it shows 0 write speed, and `iostat` drops to about 120MBps.  I am trying to figure out why fsync can't go faster, as I think it should be able to go just as fast as the initial write.

```
$ fio --name=seqwrite --rw=write --bs=1M --size=3G --directory=/mnt/raid --end_fsync=1 --numjobs=4 --group_reporting
seqwrite: (g=0): rw=write, bs=(R) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (W) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (T) 1024KiB-1024KiB, ioengine=psync, iodepth=1
...
fio-3.1
Starting 4 processes
Jobs: 2 (f=2): [_(1),F(1),_(1),F(1)][-.-%][r=0KiB/s,w=0KiB/s][r=0,w=0 IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
seqwrite: (groupid=0, jobs=4): err= 0: pid=9959: Thu Sep 12 16:47:50 2019
  write: IOPS=534, BW=534MiB/s (560MB/s)(12.0GiB/23009msec)
    clat (usec): min=315, max=21855, avg=1356.25, stdev=3850.63
     lat (usec): min=324, max=21881, avg=1373.31, stdev=3852.25
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[  322],  5.00th=[  326], 10.00th=[  330], 20.00th=[  343],
     | 30.00th=[  347], 40.00th=[  359], 50.00th=[  367], 60.00th=[  371],
     | 70.00th=[  383], 80.00th=[  445], 90.00th=[  586], 95.00th=[14746],
     | 99.00th=[19268], 99.50th=[19530], 99.90th=[21627], 99.95th=[21890],
     | 99.99th=[21890]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=14364, max=2881154, per=100.00%, avg=704062.00, stdev=949759.73, samples=35
   iops        : min=   14, max= 2813, avg=687.29, stdev=927.47, samples=35
  lat (usec)   : 500=85.28%, 750=8.30%, 1000=0.20%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.02%, 4=0.01%, 10=0.15%, 20=5.57%, 50=0.46%
  cpu          : usr=0.30%, sys=17.58%, ctx=100619, majf=0, minf=106
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwt: total=0,12288,0, short=0,0,0, dropped=0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=534MiB/s (560MB/s), 534MiB/s-534MiB/s (560MB/s-560MB/s), io=12.0GiB (12.9GB), run=23009-23009msec

Disk stats (read/write):
    md0: ios=0/3145734, merge=0/0, ticks=0/0, in_queue=0, util=0.00%, aggrios=0/6655, aggrmerge=0/778369, aggrticks=0/2292548, aggrin_queue=2292870, aggrutil=95.06%
  sda: ios=0/6502, merge=0/778634, ticks=0/3019328, in_queue=3019466, util=95.06%
  sdb: ios=0/6465, merge=0/778498, ticks=0/2554715, in_queue=2555016, util=92.24%
  sdc: ios=0/6780, merge=0/778266, ticks=0/1745808, in_queue=1746414, util=92.00%
  sdd: ios=0/6875, merge=0/778080, ticks=0/1850343, in_queue=1850585, util=91.34%
```

The array is 4 spinning disks striped with 4K chunks, and it has XFS filesystem.  If I do this same test to a single XFS disk with no RAID, it doesn't have this problem; the write speed is steady 160MBps the whole time.

Comment: have you tried reducing the kernel's buffer?  my guess is that you're getting a lot of stop/start behaviour slowing down the overall throughput.  i.e. "bufferbloat".

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the kernel's buffer, but I'll look into it

Comment: What's that the iostat of - a single disk? Your disk utilisation is apparently very high (look at the above 90% reprot for the disks in your RAID). The speed your reporting is as if a single SATA port were split into 4 (which sounds odd). If all your disks really are somehow connected to the same single SATA port then the maximum speed any single one will achieve will be limited when multiple ones are in use (assuming one disk can go faster that the divided bandwidth).